# how to create hidden web site on IIS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I need to hide web sites on the IIS 6.0. My target is to configure some user don't show and don't administrate some web sites. For example:
User1 (Group: Administrator) user only show and configure website1 
User2 (Group: Other group) user only show and configure website2

How to create hidden web sites on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If by "hidden" websites you mean control access, then it sounds like you need to wrap some sort of security, that you control, into the sites.  This can be accomplished a couple of diffrent ways:

1.) Building your own home grown authentication engine 
2.) Using ASP.NET membership (assuming you are a .Net shop)

If you want to code anything you can:

3.) Setting specific permissions in IIS (under Authentication and access control)