# How to create hidden web site on IIS - IIS with multiple user accounts

Tags: web, iis-7.5, hide, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a little server plugging along, with IIS and some other stuff. Is it possible to allow a second user access to the IIS Manager, with the ability to create and edit sites, but keep the two accounts' sites separate?

I'm not worried about security between the two accounts, just separating the two account's sites for neatness and so that one user doesn't accidentally change something tied to the other account. At the moment I have two users part of the administrators group, and if I open IIS Manager with either one they both show all the sites.

A similar question has already been asked: [how to create hidden web site on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015237/how-to-create-hidden-web-site-on-iis)

Can you please expand the answer of that thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 1**

Connecting to sites remotely would allow the other sites to appear hidden as you would only see the connecting site. See: [How to use Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 Manager to connect remotely to your website](http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-use-internet-information-services-iis-7-manager-to-connect-remotely-to-your-website/).

---

**Update 0**

As for hiding sites and other features, check out: [What is administration.config for IIS?](http://blogs.iis.net/davcox/archive/2009/12/02/what-is-administration-config-for-iis.aspx)

> One little known feature of IIS7 is that it's UI is entirely extensible!  This means that anyone can write a C# assembly and get it displayed through the IIS Manager UI.  The possibilities here are endless, anything from someone writing a new certificate management system, a website provisioning system, etc.

I haven't found documentation stating that the actual sites can be hidden but it sounds like it should be possible.

[An Overview of Feature Delegation in IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/an-overview-of-feature-delegation-in-iis) may also provide the ability to hide sites.

Other links:

- [How do I hide 'non-delegated' features in IIS 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/119419/how-do-i-hide-non-delegated-features-in-iis-7?rq=1)

---

Based on your description, Microsoft's documentation on [Configuring Permissions for IIS Manager Users and Windows Users (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) might prove helpful. For instance:

- [Allow an IIS Manager User Account to Connect to a Site or an Application (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770968%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

  > Note: For IIS Manager users to connect to sites and applications for which you grant permission, you must configure the management service to accept connections from users who have IIS Manager credentials. For more information about how to configure the management service, see [Configuring the Management Service in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754321%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
- [Configuring Permissions for IIS Manager Users and Windows Users (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) - Emphasis added.

  > Use the IIS Manager Permissions feature to **allow users to connect to sites and applications in IIS Manager. Remove a user account when you no longer want the user to configure delegated features in a site or an application.**
  >
  > **Permitted users can configure delegated features in any sites or applications for which you grant them permission.** Users can be either IIS Manager users, which are credentials created in IIS Manager by using the IIS Manager Users feature, or Windows users and groups on the local computer or on the domain to which the computer belongs.

Comment: thanks for the answer / but by this way we can not hide(invisible) that web site from other users! what can i do about that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can hide the sites, but I did add some additional information to my answer.

Comment: really really thanks for the updates, i will work on your links and accept your asnwer...

Comment: Glad I could provide some help. **Update 1** looks to be the easiest solution and closest to your requirements.

Comment: @MoonLight, which solution did you end up using?